# WooCommerce and Stripe - automatically process payment with no checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, checkout

I am building an auction website in WordPress with WooCommerce. I need to be able to automatically process payment using a customer's saved card details when an auction closes.

I already convert the product to an order when the auction ends, but cannot figure out how to process the payment too.

I don't have any code samples to share as I'm not sure where to start with this. I've looked through the Stripe and Woo docs and cannot find anything there. I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible and that perhaps it is not for security reasons.

Any pointers on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Personal opinion says that this is a really bad idea. As someone who has coded many ecommerce solutions in the past, there really should be an 'acceptance of payment' process for any transaction. That is not due to security but to protect both parties in the transaction (the buyer AND the seller).

I would look at token-based payments if you *REALLY* want to go down this route but I've unfortunately never implemented them with Stripe before.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I agree, but my client insists so I said I would see what I can do.

Comment: Well hopefully, if you get the right information your client may understand that it *may* not be the right thing to do. You can set up recurring payments through Stripe without too much bother but I am unsure as to whether these can be ad hoc. I would look at https://stripe.com/gb/billing and contact Stripe themselves to find out how possible this would be.